# Why code displays error?

Tags: matlab, logical-operators

Can you help me and explain why this code gives a error? I would like to use `XOR`, but I can not. I'm trying to do this using the following formula:"`A XOR B= (A AND ~B)OR(~A AND B)`. Can you hint what did I do wrong?

```
public = 'public';
password = 'passwd';
if length(public)== length(password)
    public = uint8(public);
    password = uint8(password);
    negpublic = ~(dec2bin(public));
    negpassword = ~(dec2bin(password));
    score = bitor(bitand(public,negpassword),bitand(negpublic,password));
    public = dec2bin(public);
    password = char(password)


else
    fprintf('length not ok!\n' );
end
```

Comment: Note that `dec2bin` returns a `char` since Matlab does not currently have a bit-data type.  Use the [bit-wise operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/bit-wise-operations.html) on integers instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I do not provide answers for homework questions, but it seems as you are almost there. The logic is done and that was the important part I guess.

Regarding the code, there is a few of bugs here. The function `dec2bin` will deceit you. As far as I know, matlab does not support binary format. The `dec2bin` actually convert the number to an array of char :(. However, having the text in binary format is not a requirement for doing bitwise operations. I cannot really see the use for a binary format in matlab since the smallest data unit for most computer achitectures normally is one byte.

You can use the function `bitcmp` (bitwise complement, which is another word for bitwise NOT) to do the negation. Secondly, bitwise operations can also work on vectors. Third, it is possible to define the negation as a variable, but bit operations are among the cheapest for most processors and operating systems so this is frankly not necessary for only two uses. So the content of everything is that you can simplify things a lot.

```
ab = 'ab'; bb = 'bb';
ab=uint8(ab); bb=uint8(bb);
bitor(bitand(ab,bitcmp(bb)), bitand(bb,bitcmp(ab)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :)
I hope that I will not be torment users simple questions :)

Answer (score 1):

*Why does the code yield error?*

Let's first list the error:

> Error using bitand Inputs must be signed or unsigned integers of the
>   same class or scalar doubles.
>
> Error in foo (line 8)
>       score = bitor(bitand(public,negpassword),bitand(negpublic,password));

Ok, so the following line yields the error:

```
score = bitor(bitand(public,negpassword),bitand(negpublic,password));
```

We can break this down and see that both the following expressions yields errors on their own

```
bitand(public,negpassword)
bitand(negpublic,password)
```

Why? If we look at the the first of these two a bit closer, we see that `public` and `negpassword` and non-compliant for use with `bitand`:

```
public =

  112  117   98  108  105   99

negpassword =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

These two must be, at the very least, of the same dimension. See [the reference for Bit-wise OR](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitor.html) for details.

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve here, but not that Matlab has its own `bitxor` function:

```
public = 'public';
password = 'passwd';
if length(public)== length(password)
    public = uint8(public);
    password = uint8(password);
    score = bitxor(public,password);
    public = dec2bin(public);
    password = char(password);
else
    fprintf('length not ok!\n' );
end
```